# In array of objects format items to have all available properties

Tags: javascript, arrays

I receive from json, an array of objects. those objects are not mapped in object:

```
[
  { 
    "key1": "val1", 
    "key2": "2019-08-23 00:00:00", 
    "key3": "val2", 
    "key4": "val3", 
    "key5": "val4" 
  }, 
  { 
    "key1": "val5", 
    "key2": "2019-08-23 00:00:00", 
    "key3": "val6"
  }, 
  {
    "key6": "val7", 
    "key7": "val8"  
  }
]
```

I have 2 issues to solve:

- first one: i want to iterate all keys of all objects and create new object that contains all unique keys and rebuild the object by adding missing keys and setting values from initial object
- second issue: i want to reformat date which arrives as string

In the end, I want to have this ouput:

```
[
  { 
    "key1": "val1", 
    "key2": "2019-08-23", 
    "key3": "val2", 
    "key4": "val3", 
    "key5": "val4" 
  }, 
  { 
    "key1": "val5", 
    "key2": "2019-08-23", 
    "key3": "val6"
    "key4": "", 
    "key5": "" 
  }, 
  {
    "key1": "", 
    "key2": "2019-08-23", 
    "key3": "", 
    "key4": "", 
    "key5": "", 
    "key5": "val7", 
    "key6": "val8"  
  }
]
```

At this stage, I found the regex

```
const regex = new RegExp(/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2})\:(\d{2})\:(\d{2})/);
```

And tried this:
I first declare my json object as a variable "documents"

I retrieve all unique keys in an array:

```
let keyArr = [];
documents.forEach((document) => {
    Object.keys(document).forEach((key) => {
        if(!keyArr.includes(key)) {
            keyArr.push(key);
        }
    });
});
```

As output I have

```
['key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4',  'key5', 'key6']
```

Now i'm declaring two variables:

```
let objToMap = {};
let returnValue = [];
```

My last step consists on populating the objects and push them into the array:

```
documents.forEach(document => {
    let objToMap = {};
    for (let i = 0; i< keyArr.length; i++) {
        Object.entries(document).forEach((key) => {
            // on parcoure chaque objet document et on veut récupérer la clé et la valeur
            // on veut savoir si le tableau de clés 
            // key retour la clés valeur d'un objet. key = > [ 'CODECLI', '012' ]

            let keyName = key[0];
            let value = key[1];
            if(keyName == keyArr[i]) {
                objToMap = { ...objToMap, [keyArr[i]]: value };
            } else {
                objToMap = { ...objToMap, [keyArr[i]]: "NC" };
            }

        });
    }
    returnValue.push(objToMap);
});
```

I think i have a logic issue. The result I obtain is not as expected

```
[
  { 
    "key1": "NC", 
    "key2": "NC", 
    "key3": "NC", 
    "key4": "NC", 
    "key5": "val4" 
  }, 
  ...

]
```

Comment: In your example output, why does the third element have `key6` while the others do not? And where is the date (`key2`) coming from in the third element?

Comment: The output comes from different sources. For example: I retrieve columns from a first table, other from other table, most of the columns names are different and my goal is to display the outputs in a same table. It means that i have to reformat the data in order not to fill the columns where an object has no value :) I hope I give you suitable explaination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all unique keys by iterating over the array items using `Array.reduce()` and using spread syntax.

And after getting the unique keys, you can iterate over the array and the keys for the second time but this time using `Array.map()`

```js
const items = [{"key1":"val1","key2":"2019-08-23 00:00:00","key3":"val2","key4":"val3","key5":"val4"},{"key1":"val5","key2":"2019-08-23 00:00:00","key3":"val6"},{"key6":"val7","key7":"val8"}]

const uniqueKeys = Array.from(new Set(items.reduce((acc, cur) => ([...acc, ...Object.keys(cur)]), [])))

const dateRegex = new RegExp(/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2})\:(\d{2})\:(\d{2})/);

const convertedItems = items.map(item => {
  uniqueKeys.forEach(key => {
    if (item[key] && dateRegex.test(item[key])) {
      item[key] = item[key].split(' ')[0]
    }
    
    if(!item[key]){
      item[key] = ""
    }

  })
  return item;
})

console.log(convertedItems)
```

Comment: Thanks ! it works perfectly. I should inprove my knowledge in JS :)

Answer (score 1):

Do one pass through the source array to retrieve unique keys and another pass to format all array items:

```js
const src = [{key1:"val1",key2:"2019-08-23 00:00:00",key3:"val2",key4:"val3",key5:"val4"},{key1:"val5",key2:"2019-08-23 00:00:00",key3:"val6"},{key6:"val7",key7:"val8"}],

      keys = [...new Set(src.flatMap(Object.keys))],
      
      result = src.map(item => 
        Object.assign(
          ...keys.map(key => ({
            [key]: item[key] === undefined
              ? ''
              : key === 'key2'
                  ? item[key].replace(/\s.*/, '')
                  : item[key]
          }))
        ))
        
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%}
```